# Custom validator with validation helpers in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid, activemodel

I've defined a **class** which is getting **fat** because of many validations defined in it. So, I created a custom validator which includes all validations specific to a given context, and it's working fine.

But the issue is that, while **validaing any attribute**, the **options** which are passed while defining a validation aren't getting considered.

Consider this `Post` class,

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :state
  field :description

  validates_with PublishableValidator, on: :publish
end
```

Now, while publishing a post, its description is mandatory. So I am validating it with **publish** context.

```
@post.valid?(:publish)
```

Custom validator for all publishable validations is defined as,

```
class PublishableValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :description, presence: true, unless: :admin?

  def validate(post)
    self.class.validators.each do |validator|
      validator.validate(post)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, there is constraint in **description** validation that, for admin, don't run this validation( not a good idea but admin can do whatever they want :] ).

But when I validate it with blank description and admin privilege, it still gives error, without considering provided constraint.

Suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using `SimpleDelegator` class.

- First, I inherited `PublishableValidator` from `SimpleDelegator`.
- Delegated `PublishableValidator` object to `@post`.
- Ran validations on publishable object.
- And last, merged publishable errors to `post` object.

**Updated `PublishableValidator`**

```
class PublishableValidator < SimpleDelegator
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :description, presence: true, unless: :admin?

  def validate(post)
    self.__setobj__(post)
    super

    post.errors.messages.merge!(self.errors.messages)
  end
end
```

Thanks to this [blog](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/05/mastering-rails-validations-objectify)